# How to initiate stand alone Java app to use my sql connection pools?

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish, netbeans-7, connection-pooling

I inherited this code (which worked) for a stand alone Java application (Netbeans 7.3, openjdk7, glassfish-3.1.2.2, mysql5.5):

```
fDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
fDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
Class.forName(fDriver);
fCon =DriverManager.getConnection (fDatabase,"username","password");
```

I'm now trying to convert it to a connection pool which is defined in the glassfish web console.

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/mydb/"); //this is the jndi name showing app in the web console of glassfish
fCon2 = ds.getConnection("username","password");
```

I'm getting (for the ctx.lookup line):

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException:
>   Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an
>   applet parameter, or in an application resource file: 
>   java.naming.factory.initial

What basic code am I missing?

Comment: Try this  java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb/ in your lookup method?

Comment: @Octopus: no. It didn't help

Comment: @Octopus: just to be clear the jndi name is: jdbc/mydb

Comment: you need to specify the Initial context class and add its dependent jar files

Comment: @mateen: can you elaborate on this initial context class?

Comment: For example following configurations must be used for glass fish


HashTable ht = new HashTable();
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://localhost:4848");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(ht);


Add the corresponding glassfish jar's.


Note: The Initial context factory and the provider Url changes for every application server. This means the same configuration you can't use for weblogic server

Comment: I'm getting a namingexception when I call new InitialContext.What do you mean by: "add the corresponding glassfish jar's?